# How to push SystemUI APK or any framework App like Deskclock etc. after building it in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

How to push SystemUI APK or any systemui after building it in AOSP ?
so I have already cloned, repo synced and then changed some code in AOSP's codebase in a package called "**SystemUI**". and after that I did **make SystemUI**.

It generated the APK that is present in out/ folder.

How to push it to the emulator/pixel ? Where to push it ?

Comment: You should disable verity first, then it can be done by adb root && adb remount && sleep 15 && adb push ..... && adb reboot